# JS select2 . trigger solo me toma el ultimo valor de array

Tags: javascript, jquery, nodejs

tengo una query la cual me trae datos de mi BD , extrae las id y a traves de de jquery le asigno los daos seleccioandos a un select multiple ,

**JS**

```
     resultados = data.resultados;
          console.log(resultados)
                for (let i = 0; i < data.resultados.length; i++) {
                    var res = resultados[i].valor
                    console.log(res)


                }
                $("#slcApp").select2().val(res).trigger('change');
```

Asi me muestra los datos del resultado traidos de la consola

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el el resultado del valor le asigno una variable RES y eso se lo asigno al val de mi jquery , pero solo me toma el valor 6 , cuando me deberia mostrar 2 valores .

**MULTISELECT**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que sólo estas recorriendo el arreglo pero en ningún momento lo guardas en alguna variable, por eso por cada iteración pisa el registro.

```js
const data = [
   {valor: 5, desc: 'Sistema de Minería', idPerfil: 14 },
   {valor: 6, desc: 'Gestión', idPerfil: 14 }
]

const valores = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      valores.push(data[i].valor);
}
console.log(valores);
```

Lo que debes hacer es crear una variable y guardar cada iteración en la misma

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvio un monton :)